# Issue with react using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have 3 main components.

this component render the whole app

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

import IndexContent from './components/indexContent';
import IndexHome from './components/IndexHome';
import Root from './components/root';

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Match, Miss} from 'react-router';


   class Home extends Component{

    return(
            <Router>
                    <div>
                        <Root />
                        <Match exactly pattern='/' component={IndexContent}/>
                        <Match pattern="/indexhome" component={IndexHome}/>
                    </div>
            </Router>
        )

};

export default Home;
```

In this component I have the navBar and the footer and in the {this.props.children} I want that the clicked component will be rendered.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

import NavBar from './NavBar';
import Footer from './footer';

class Root extends Component{
    render:function(){
        return(
               <div>
                  <NavBar/>
                  {this.props.children}
                  <Footer/>
              </div>
        )
    }
};

export default Root;
```

And I have another component with a Link

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';
<Link to="/indexhome">Join In</Link>
```

I try for a week now to get it work. I understand that there is this new version of 'react-router' and the syntax might be a problem.

What am I doing wrong if all I want is that by Default the index page is the {IndexContent} and when clicking the Link the {IndexHome} will be rendered?

the {Root} is a way to let navBar and footer be in all pages

Comment: two questions for you: 1. what version of `react-router` are you using? 2. you simply want a `nav-bar` that will render the component that the router provides without re:render the "layout" (your `Root` component)?

Comment: Hi,
1. using react-router version 4.0.0
2. no, I want to have the {IndexContent} to be the homePage (first page you see) and When clicking the Link Tag (in a third component) the {IndexHome} will be rendered.
If it is possible I want that the {Root} to handle the renders so the {Footer} and the {NavBar} will stay in all pages.

Comment: something like this? http://imgur.com/C0je8Sa

Comment: yes, exactly ..

Answer (score -1):

You're using an old alpha version of React Router. Both `Match` and `Miss` are no longer components. Also, you need to import from `react-router-dom`, not `react-router`. There are a lot of examples on the [documentation page](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web) that I recommend you take a look at. Install the latest version of React Router and here's some code to get you started,

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Root />
    <Route exactly pattern='/' component={IndexContent}/>
    <Route pattern="/indexhome" component={IndexHome}/>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is what you are trying to achive: [image]

here is a very abstract and simple example (you can change and omit the use of redux provider if you're not using redux ):
consider this entry point:

```
 // index.js - this is your entry point

import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from 'path/to/component';
import HomePage from 'path/to/component';
import AboutPage from 'path/to/component';
import NotFoundPage from 'path/to/component';
//...
  render( 
    <Provider store={store} >
      <Router routes={
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
          <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
        </Route>
      } />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

notice how we have 1 "main" route that reference the `App` component, and it has "child routes" that reference other components based on the `path` we define of course. with that in mind, one of `react-router`'s jobs is to pass down the "child components" to the parent `App` component, again based on the url -> path provided. it does that via `props.children`.
Now, you can place the child components anywhere you want on your `App` component or pass them farther down.
In this example, we are rendering a `Header` component, a `child` component that we got from `react-router` and finally a `Footer` component:

```
// App.js 

import React from 'react';
import Header from 'path/to/component';
import Footer from 'path/to/component';
//...
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                
                {this.props.children /* here are the children that react-router will pass down */} 
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

This way, only the `props.children` are being re-render on each route change, letting the `App` , `Header` and `Footer` remain "static".
Of course the styling is up to you, and the names of the components are just for the sake of this example.
**PLEASE NOTE - this is relevant for react-router v3.0.0**